# Documentation for DocBook5 ISO 690 bibliography

Tags: documentation, docbook, bibliography, docbook-5

I would like to use docbook5's support for ISO 690 formatted bibliographies but I can not find proper documentation. My search led me to the sites [1](http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/CustomBiblio.html), [2](http://wiki.docbook.org/ISO690Bibliography) and [3](http://wiki.docbook.org/ISO690Bibliography?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=doc.html) containing (broken) links to each other and the last one being inaccessible due to a 502 Proxy Error.

Is there a mirror serving the above mentioned information? Or where else can I find "the DocBook XML elements and attributes to use for each type of referenced document" as stated in [1](http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/CustomBiblio.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is available as an attachment to the page that you link to (link 2): http://wiki.docbook.org/ISO690Bibliography. The direct link to the attachment is your link 3: http://wiki.docbook.org/ISO690Bibliography?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=doc.html. Both these links work for me.

However, the DocBook wiki has been slow and unreliable for some time. If you have problems with the above links, the documentation is also available as an attachment to this mailing list message: http://markmail.org/message/n2qumyhk2togibuf.